# How to root the LGLS676? Is the idea I have about how to go about it the most efficient method?

Tags: rooting, 6.0-marshmallow, linux, lg

I want to root my LGLS676, because I want to install the gnu coreutils on my android phone. The only way I can imagine doing this is making the phone think it's not a phone, because I can't use adb because all my laptops are running Debian 11 Gnu/Linux, and LG doesn't seem to provide Linux USB drivers. The only way I can think of to make my phone think it's not a phone is to take out its hard drive, RAM, and/or cpu and then write the gnu coreutils and su onto the phone's hard drive. Is this the right way to go about rooting the LGLS676 in my circumstances? If not, what should I do to root the phone? I don't know at the moment what version of android it's running, but I think it's Android *Marshmallow*. Going into recovery mode and trying to boot into the boot loader from there just boots into the normal login screen instead.

Comment: I have never seen an Linux computer that requires special drivers for adb. Only Windows requires special drivers, on Linux there is an generic adb driver available which should work with all (or most?) devices. On some systems you have to change some permissions to make adb work but that should be everything.

Comment: I didn't know there was a generic adb driver for Linux. Is it installed automatically with the adb package or is it something that has to be installed separately? If it has to be installed separately, can you post a link to it or the package name for it in Debian repos?

Comment: The [official Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb) says that Linux users shouldn't need to install USB drivers. Have you [enabled Developers options and USB Debugging](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device) instead?

Comment: I have enabled Dev options and USB debugging. When I have time, I'll try to get the bootloader unlocked or the gnu coreutils installed over adb. I have a bit of stuff to do though, so I won't be available for about 6 hours.

Comment: I tried rooting it, and ended up destroying my computer (figuratively speaking, of course.) Now I need to hope a bunch of stuff went right for my computer to boot. Lesson learned: be even more careful.

Comment: The stuff went right.